# How to use multiple authentication passwords in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-passport

The auth.php file has the following code

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'apidriver' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'drivers',
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'drivers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Driver::class,
        ],

    ],
```

And this is the authentication code for the driver

```
  if (Auth::guard('apidriver')->attempt(['email'=>request('email'),
  'password'=>request('password')])) {

  $driver=Auth::guard('apidriver')->user();

  $success['token'] =  $driver->createToken('Pizza App')->accessToken;

  return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);

}else{

return response()->json(['errorrr'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);

  }
```

And generates the following error when accessing

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt()

When the user authentication code is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

You are not parsing your request parameters properly,
replace this line

```
if(Auth::guard('apidriver')>attempt(['email'=>request('email'),'password'=>request('password')]))
```

with this:

```
if (Auth::guard('apidriver')->attempt(['email'=>request('email'),'password'=>request('password')]))
```

Also check that you called `Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your class.